# Instantiating a class into a variable or not

Tags: c#

Is there a difference in terms of performance between these two ways of writing code that is functionally equivalent?

**Option 1:**

```
SomeObjecModel TheObjectModel = new SomeObjectModel();
return TheObjectModel.SomeMethod();
```

**Option 2:**

```
return  new SomeObjectModel().SomeMethod();
```

In option 1 the object is instantiated into a variable whereas in option 2 there's no variable. I'm just curious if there's any difference.

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I'm about to get off a train so won't be able to find it. Short answer: no performance difference; the first version may make debugging easier... but please follow variable naming conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference in the generated IL code:

```
Option1:
IL_0000:  newobj      UserQuery+SomeObjectModel..ctor
IL_0005:  stloc.0     // TheObjectModel
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     // TheObjectModel
IL_0007:  callvirt    UserQuery+SomeObjectModel.SomeMethod
IL_000C:  ret         

Option2:
IL_0000:  newobj      UserQuery+SomeObjectModel..ctor
IL_0005:  call        UserQuery+SomeObjectModel.SomeMethod
IL_000A:  ret
```

(compiled in LinqPad with optimizations turned on)

However it's unlikely to make a noticeable difference at runtime.

Answer (score 7):

There is likely going to be no measurable difference.  In both cases, the vast majority of the time spent will be instantiating the object, as well as executing your method.

Use the version you find more readable (and hence maintainable).

Answer (score 5):

There WAS - in case of a breakpoint you had no way to see the value in the debugger (as you could only set a breakpoint BEFORE the return.

So, I often used the first syntax to be able to set a breakpoint on the return and see the value. I would actually even put the SomeMethod() call into a varaible for the exact same reason.

Since VS 2013 Update 1 or 2 the return values are explicitly available in the debugger, so the first syntax is moot.

The update is described here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/27/seeing-function-return-values-in-the-debugger-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Either way you are creating a variable.  One is just done inline.  I would be more worried about whether that variable needs to be disposed of.  If so, I would prefer to see everything wrapped in a 'using' statement.

Comment: to wrap inside 'using' required to implement IDispoible. In this case variable will collect by GC after the scope

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between these two methods of writing code. In first option `GC` will collect the variable after the scope. It is not a matter what style you choose to write the code and the compiler would convert and compile to lower level code from higher level.

eg: Yoy can use `Delegate` instead of `Action` and both are serving the same functionality but the coding style is different. So compiler will always convert this `Action`(higlevel) statement into `Delegate`(low level)

Comment: Yeah. Ever used a debugger ;)?

Answer (score 0):

There won't be a performance difference. Because if you check that IL code, it is giving a name to the constructor after creating it. In any case, you should prefer which one is more readable.

```
Option1:
IL_0000:  newobj      UserQuery+SomeObjectModel..ctor
IL_0005:  stloc.0     // TheObjectModel
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     // TheObjectModel
IL_0007:  callvirt    UserQuery+SomeObjectModel.SomeMethod
IL_000C:  ret         

Option2:
IL_0000:  newobj      UserQuery+SomeObjectModel..ctor
IL_0005:  call        UserQuery+SomeObjectModel.SomeMethod
IL_000A:  ret
```

Before callvirt was used, it was possible to call a method on a null instance of a class. To avoid null calls callvirt has been created in the first option.

Comment: There is almost certainly *not* going to be a difference.  The second code snippet still needs to store the result of the constructor call somewhere.  It's just storing it in an implicit and unnamed storage location.  Giving that storage location a name doesn't have any performance cost at all.

Comment: @Servy I just saw the IL code. You are definitely right about that. That's why I said might be a small impact. But it seems like you are absolutely right.